# Read sms shows only current month sms

Tags: android, sms

I am trying to dump sms to text file but it only reads current month messages starting from date 1 upto current date. How can i possibly read all sms without setting app as default or anything like that?

```
public List<Sms> getAllSms() {
    List<Sms> lstSms = new ArrayList<Sms>();
    Sms objSms = new Sms();
    Uri message = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
    ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();

    Cursor c = cr.query(message, null, null, null, null);
    this.startManagingCursor(c);
    int totalSMS = c.getCount();

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < totalSMS; i++) {

            objSms = new Sms();
            objSms.setId(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id")));
            objSms.setAddress(c.getString(c
                                          .getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")));
            objSms.setMsg(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")));
            objSms.setReadState(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("read")));
            String date = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date"));
            Long timestamp = Long.parseLong(date);    
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
            Date finaldate = calendar.getTime();
            objSms.setTime(finaldate.toString());
            if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type")).contains("1")) {
                objSms.setFolderName("inbox");
            } else {
                objSms.setFolderName("sent");
            }

            lstSms.add(objSms);
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    // else {
    // throw new RuntimeException("You have no SMS");
    // }
    c.close();

    return lstSms;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading inbox and sent seperately solved my issue